# Time Series Cross Validation in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to do time series cross validation in R using tsCV() function from the forecast package. I have a doubt regarding the forecast horizon parameter "h" in this function. If the value of h is > 1, the function returns a matrix, containing error corresponding to each forecast horizon. Let's say h is defined as 4. What exactly does the error column corresponding to h=4 in output indicate:

a) Does it give the errors evaluated based on only 1 forecasted point which is the 4th forecasted point in this case.
b) Or does it give errors evaluated based on all the 4 forecasted points i.e. taking into account errors for all the 4 forecasted points.

Comment: https://otexts.org/fpp2/accuracy.html#time-series-cross-validation

Comment: In the above link, for 4 step ahead forecasts, only the 4th point is marked in red(i.e. test set). There lies my confusion. In this case, does tsCV() function gives errors based on only the 4th forecasted point in forecast horizon, or does it take into account the errors made in first 3 points as well. Can i check the combined error based on all the 4 forecasted points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the help file. It is very clear on this point. Here is an extract:

> Let `y` contain the time series `y[1:T]`. Then `forecastfunction` is applied successively to the time series `y[1:t]`, for `t=1,…,T-h`, making predictions `f[t+h]`. The errors are given by `e[t+h] = y[t+h]-f[t+h]`. If `h=1`, these are returned as a vector, `e[1:T]`. For `h>1`, they are returned as a matrix with the `h`th column containing errors for forecast horizon `h`. The first few errors may be missing as it may not be possible to apply `forecastfunction` to very short time series.